# Looker embedded JavaScript events does not work

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

[image: 1]

I am trying to create a looker dashboard as above picture, but the callback event does not work, anyone knows what happened?

All events doesn't work:
dashboard:run:loaded
dashboard:run:compolete
page:properties:changed

Thanks in advance.

```
LookerEmbedSDK.createDashboardWithId(data.lookerId)
            .withParams({
                ...
            })
      .appendTo(`#${data.containerId}`)
            .on('dashboard:run:loaded', () => {
                console.log('dashboard loaded---');
            })
            .on('dashboard:run:start', () => {
                console.log('Starting create dashboard---');
            })
            .on('dashboard:run:complete', () => {
                //TODO: Create next dashboard
                console.log('Continue to next');
            })
      .on('page:properties:changed', e => test(e.height, testA(data.containerId)))
      .build()
      .connect()
      .then(setupDashboard)
      .catch((error: Error) => {
        console.error('An unexpected error occurred', error);
      });
    };
```